# Express: SetHeader 'Cache-Control' for a single file after setting maxAge

Tags: node.js, express, cache-control

node newbie here. The below code results in all files receiving the response header "Cache-Control public, max-age=31536000". I would like the index to have a max-age of 0. I have tried several different methods but the root of it seems to be a more fundamental misunderstanding on my part.

Why does the below res.setHeader line not take effect (so that I can understand my misconception) and what would be the correct method to ensure Index.html is not cached?

```js
var express    = require('express'),
    gzipStatic = require('connect-gzip-static'),
    app        = express(),
   
    port= process.env.PORT || 3030,
    cacheAge = 365 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000;

app.use(gzipStatic(__dirname + '/public', { maxAge: cacheAge }));

app.get('/', function(req, res) {
    res.setHeader('Cache-Control', 'max-age=0');
    res.sendFile('index.html');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to set header in app.use():

```
app.use(function (req, res, next) {
  ......

  res.setHeader('Cache-Control', 'public, max-age=31557600'); // 1 year

  ......
})
```